# describe select query

Tags: select, describe

DESCRIBE (or SHOW COLUMNS) does not seem to work except for a table.

I want to be able to retrieve the equivalent of DESCRIBE `<table>`, but for an arbitrarily complex `SELECT` query.

For example, I would like to say:

> `DESCRIBE (arbitrary SELECT statement) AS`table2

where the `SELECT` statement might contain JOINs and so on

In the simplest case

```
 DESCRIBE (SELECT * from table1) as table2
```

should yield the same results as

```
 DESCRIBE table1
```

Is there some SQL that I can use to get this, or something like it?

Comment: Which DBMS are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are working with MySQL (Although this should work anyway). As of version 5.0.1, the DESCRIBE statement also works for views (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html). Therefore, what you need to do is save your SELECT query as a view and execute a describe on the view:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM mytable;
DESCRIBE myview
```